# Solidity TronIDE - Revert opcode executed on return value

Tags: solidity, revert, contract

I'm working on a new Smart Contract for TRON.
I need to sum each amount of paying. But when I get the value, I got a REVERT error:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Test {

    uint counter = 0;


    function add() public payable {
        counter += msg.value;
    }


    function getCounter() public view returns(uint){
        return counter;
    }

}
```

The "getCounter" return REVERT error. Why? How can I manage sum of msg.value's ?

Comment: Are you sending any `value` along with the transaction that executes the `getCounter()` function?

Comment: Of course, with TronIDE.io I send 100 TRX, not sun. The transaction is correct, and the balance of my Testnet TRX address was paid of 100 TRX.

Comment: I have seen the transaction on tronscan.org, txnID:26f39a8cf32e17ab808fbd939e6a0adf768876ca7aff2f11c2a2ce9db2352a2b - I've seen the contract TC2w4X2AmSrpphp2xPHorCGF8ywTHwuKeL in the Shasta Network, and the read contract method getCounter() return me `root:"100000000"`. So the issue is in the TRON-IDE Interface.

Answer (score 1):

When you're executing the `add()` function sending along non-zero `value`, it executes correctly because the function is `payable`.

However the `getCounter()` is not `payable` so you need to execute it with zero `value` (or add the `payable` modifier` to the function).

Comment: You are right. Thanks so much.